# Receiving "ImportError: cannot import name" with QGIS Plugin Builder

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qt

While doing a first-time attempt to craft a simple plugin, I ran into this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name

I am using QGIS 2.6.0 for windows, the QT Designer that comes with that package, and the plugin builder plugin 2.0.3

I created the simplest of UI's almost identical to that found at:
   http://anitagraser.com/2014/04/26/getting-started-writing-qgis-2-x-plugins/

Compiled the UI and resource file, as instructed, and then placed the folder within the bounds of the QGIS folders.

Opening QGIS, then the plugin manager, I saw my plugin, and attempted to click it, and the DLG box reported this error [full stack, below "==="):

File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\TestPlugin\testplugindialog.py", line 24, in 
    from ui_testplugin import Ui_TestPlugin
ImportError: cannot import name Ui_TestPlugin

I infer a circular import, or other problem, but that file referred to is created by the Plugin Builder.

Can anyone provide any hints as to why this error is popping up?

---

Couldn't load plugin TestPlugin due an error when calling its classFactory() method

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 208, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\TestPlugin\__init__.py", line 26, in classFactory
    from testplugin import TestPlugin
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 460, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\TestPlugin\testplugin.py", line 29, in 
    from testplugindialog import TestPluginDialog
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 460, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\TestPlugin\testplugindialog.py", line 24, in 
    from ui_testplugin import Ui_TestPlugin
ImportError: cannot import name Ui_TestPlugin
```

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: I think you have to place your compiled folder here: `C:\Users\(your user name)\.qgis2\python\plugins`. See if this works.

Comment: did you do pyuic4 -o ui_buildertest.py ui_buildertest.ui ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had not changed the object name for the dialog object in QT.   I assumed in error, that the name was generic/default, and carried as such over to the plugin builder.  Once I changed the dialog object name, it worked.  The hint came from the class name's mismatch within compiled code.